# Does a machine learning algorithm copy the data it learns from?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning

I am not a programmer, rather a law student, but I am currently researching for a project involving artificial intelligence and copyright law. I am currently looking at whether the learning process of a machine learning algorithm may be copyright infringement if a protected work is used by the algorithm. However, this relies on whether or not the algorithm copies the work or does something else.

Can anyone tell me whether machine learning algorithms typically copy the data (picture/text/video/etc.) they are analysing (even if only briefly) or if they are able to obtain the required information from the data through other methods that do not require copying (akin to a human looking at a stop sign and recognising it as a stop sign without necessarily copying the image).

Apologies for my lack of knowledge and I'm sorry if any of my explanation flies in the face of any established machine learning knowledge. As I said, I am merely a lowly law student.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

A few machine learning algorithms actually retain a copy of the training set, for example k-nearest neighbours. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance-based_learning. Not all do this; in fact it is usually regarded as a disadvantage, because the training set can be large.

Also, computers are also built round a number of different stores of data of different sizes and speeds. They usually copy data they are working on to small fast stores while they are working on it, because the larger stores take much longer to read and write. One of many possible examples of this has been the subject of legal wrangling of which I know little - see e.g. https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/2223/why-does-browser-cache-not-count-as-copyright-infringement and others for browser cache copyright. If a computer has added two numbers, it will certainly have stored them in its internal memory. It is very likely that it will have stored at least one of them in what are called internal registers - very small very fast memory intended for storing numbers to be worked on.

If a computer (or any other piece of electronic equipment) has been used to process classified data, it is usual to treat it as classified from then on, making the worst case assumption that it might have retained some copy of any of the data it has been used to process, even if retrieving that data from it would in practice require a great deal of specialised expertise with specialised equipment.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, no. The first thing that typical ML algorithms do with their inputs is not to copy or store it, but to compute something based on it and then forget the original. And this is a fair description of what neural networks, regression algorithms and statistical methods do. There is no 'eidetic memory' in mainstream ML. I imagine anything doing that would be marketed as a database or a full text indexing engine or somesuch.

But how will you present your data to an algorithm running on a machine without first copying the data to that machine?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chris. In terms of how the algorithm gets the data, in the case where it is given a defined set of data, this can be licenced from the copyright owners for this purpose and should not pose too many tricky legal problems. What I am more interested in is if the algorithm inadvertently uses a protected work that has not been licensed and whether or not this is copyright infringement.

Is this possible for an algorithm to do or do they always operate based on a defined set of training data?

Comment: expand on "inadvertently uses"? If it's presented to the algorithm as training data, then it's not inadvertent. If it's seen in use after training – ah, that's tricky. The mainstream (not all) approach is currently to *not* learn or remember after training (although I wouldn't bet on it remaining the mainstream approach in 5-10 years).

Comment: I guess my main question here is would it be possible for a machine learning algorithm to use data during training that was not explicitly provided to it? 

For example, is it possible for me as a programmer to set my algorithm to trawl the internet for pictures of stop signs to get a much data as possible to train itself with?

Comment: Then I think your category of "inadvertent uses" doesn't exist. Computers only do what they are explicitly programmed to. 
Yes you can program it to trawl the internet. Google used random youtube videos when training their face/cat detector. But in my mind, that is explicitly providing, not inadvertent use : it would only trawl if programmed to do so.
But yes, this means you're trawling works to which you have no right. And yes, I'd then stand by my answer of "Typically, it's not copied, except for when it's first copied to the machine"

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot. I think my use of the word "inadvertent" was misplaced. What I meant was using a specific piece of data that was not explicitly known to the developer in the course of trawling the internet for data. Thanks again for your help, it is certainly an interesting issue that most countries are not prepared for in their legal frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

> Does a machine learning algorithm copy the data it learns from?

There are many different machine learning algorithms. If you are talking about [k nearest neighbor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) (k-NN) then the answer is simply **yes**.

However, k-NN is rarely used. Most (all?) other models are not that simple. Usually, a machine learning developer wants the training data to be compressed (a lot, lossy) by the model for several reasons: (1) The amount of training data is large (many GB), (2) Generalization might be better if the training data is compressed (3) inference of new examples might take really long if the data is not compressed. (By "compress", I mean that the relevant information for the task is extracted and irrelevant data is removed. Not compression in the usual sense.)

For other models than k-NN, the answer is more complicated. **It depends** on what you consider a "copy". For example, from artificial neural networks (especially the sub-type of [convolutional neural networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network), short: CNNs) the training data can partially be restored. Those models ware state of the art for many (all?) computer vision tasks.

I could not find papers which show that you can (partially) restore / extract training data from CNNs with the focus on possible privacy / copyright problems, but I'm ~70% certain I have read an abstract about this problem. I think I've also heard a talk where a researcher said this was a problem when building a detector for child pornography. However, I don't think that was recorded or anything published about this.

Here are two papers which indicate that restoring training data from CNNs might be possible:

- [Understanding deep learning requires rethinking generalization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.03530)
- [Visualizing Deep Convolutional Neural Networks Using Natural Pre-Images](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02017) and the [Zeiler & Fergus paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.2901)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by the word "copy". If you run any program, it will copy the data from the hard disk to RAM for processing. I am assuming this is not what you meant.

So let's say you have the copyrighted data in a particular machine and you run your machine learning algorithms on the data, then there is no reason for the algorithm to copy the data out of the machine.

On the other hand, if you use a cloud ML service(AWS/IBM Bluemix/Azure), then you need to upload the data to the cloud before you can run ML algorithms. This would mean you are copying the data.

Hopefully this sheds more light !

Lowly ML student

Answer (score 0):

Some of the machines do copy the data set such as KNN. Unfortunately, such algorithms are not commonly used in practice because they can't be scaled for large data set.

Most ML algorithms use the data set to identify a pattern, that's why pattern recognition is another name for machine learning. The pattern is almost always much smaller (in terms of memory and variables etc) than the original data set.